# Почему выскакиевает Unknown column '*' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['newname']))    
    {
        $nick=$_POST['nazv'];
        $new_name_theme=mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `названия` (наименование) 
        VALUES(`$nick`)")or die(mysql_error());
        echo "account is added";
        if($_POST['nazv']==false)
        {
        echo 'your account is not set';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не пробовали дать названия столбцам английскими буквами?

И у вас разве в этом месте появляется ошибка?

И какая-то странная у вас логика - сначала добавляете запись из переменной, а потом проверяете  содержимое этой переменной...

Comment: как посоветуете сделать проверку:задал ли пользователь input type='text' повторное название(значение) или он его вовсе не заполнил?

Comment: 1. Не ясно зачем нужен $_POST['newname'], если он в коде не используется. Поэтому его уберу.
2. Если пользователь не отправил значение (не заполнил поле), то isset($_POST['nazv']) == false;

Кроме того, пользователь мог передать пробелы. Поэтому дополнительно делаем trim и проверяем на пустоту.

3. Про SQL-injection слышали? Лучше почитать.

---

Т.е. если грубо:

    if (isset($_POST['nazv']) && trim($_POST['nazv']) != '') {
        // ... ваши действия
        echo "account is added";
    } else {
        echo 'your account is not set';
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь прислать точный запрос, отправляемый в бд?

---

в идеале синтаксис должен быть таким

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`tabname` (`param1`,`param2`,`param3`) VALUES ('val1','val2','val3')
```

Попробуйте задать имена таблиц и полей латинскими буквами

Comment: INSERT INTO `test`.`названия` (`наименование`) VALUES ('гипножаба');

Comment: в идеале синтаксис должен быть таким
INSERT INTO ~test~.~tabname~ (~param1~,~param2~,~param3~) VALUES ('val1','val2','val3')
Попробуйте задать имена таблиц и полей латинскими буквами
печально, что нет возможности добавлять косую одинарную ковычку (которая на букве ё). Поставлю вместо неё тильду ~

Comment: подставил именно такой вариант. сработало. но не понимаю почему исходный вариант не работает

Comment: вариантов может быть тьма, вплоть до неверной кодировки файла, в котором формируется запрос.или в конфигах sql. рекомендую Вам всегда использовать только латинские символы и всегда ставить нужные ковычки

Comment: я самостоятельно обучаюсь т.к взял тему диплома не по направлеию специальности(вообщем не было бд и php)мне руководительтемы сказал делай русскими чтобы было понятно( я про себя ну ок(руководитель-студент 3го курса гуап) я же  студент 4ого курса колледжа а наслышан  что все ругают кириллицу в коде да и вообще... странный руководитель )

Comment: обрати внимание, в VALUES() должны быть другие кавычки
 VALUES('$nick') - вот так

Answer (score 0):

"наименование" тоже в кавычках должно быть. К тому же, у вас SQL injection.

Comment: SQL injection?
поподробнее пожалуйста. что это значит?

Comment: http://goo.gl/v7anu
$nick = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nazv']);